OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context Python code
I am trying to connect to an ip and listen to that port. I keep getting this error message OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context It was working when I was using my local IP(127.0.0.1) Why won't it work now? I am also able to ping the ip I want to reach along with the port. This is th full error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\rcouillard\listen.py", line 93, in <module>     receive_data()   File "C:\Users\rcouillard\listen.py", line 58, in receive_data     server_socket.bind(server_address) OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
import socket
import mysql.connector
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime

# Configure logging

log_directory = "C:/logs/"
if not os.path.exists(log_directory):
os.makedirs(log_directory)

log_filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d\_%H-%M-%S") + "\_sanilog.txt"
log_file_path = os.path.join(log_directory, log_filename)

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_path, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

# Function to create a connection to the MySQL database

def create_connection():
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="",
database="saniscalesample"
)
return conn

# Function to insert data into the database

def insert_data(conn, raw_data, connection, reply_port=10001):
data = raw_data.replace("TRANSACTION=", "")
data = data.replace("\<lf\>", "").replace("\<cr\>", "")
data_parts = \[part for part in data.split(";") if part.strip()\]

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO truckweigh (ï»¿trans_num, trans_type, truck_num, weight_kg, weight_lbs, weights_t, weight_man, weight_date, in_num, tare_kg, tare_lbs, tare_t, tare_man, tare_date, net_kg, net_lbs, net_t, net_date, legal_state)
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(query, tuple(data_parts))
    conn.commit()
    
    # Construct reply message
    transaction_number = data_parts[0]  # Extract transaction number from the data
    reply_message = f"F#20=DELETE={transaction_number}<cr><lf>"
    logging.info(f"Replying with: {reply_message}")
    
    # Send back confirmation with reply message
    reply_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    reply_socket.connect(("10.13.98.xxx", reply_port))
    reply_socket.sendall(reply_message.encode())
    reply_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)  # Shutdown the write side of the connection
    reply_socket.close()  # Close the connection

# Function to receive data

def receive_data():
\# Create a socket object
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to the address
    server_address = ('10.13.98.xxx', 8080) 
    server_socket.bind(server_address)
    
    # Listen for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(1)
    
    # Connect to the database
    conn = create_connection()
    
    logging.info("Listening for connections...")
    
    while True:
        # Accept a connection
        connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        
        try:
            # Log connection information
            logging.info(f"Connection from: {client_address}")
            
            # Receive data
            data = connection.recv(1024).decode()
            if data:
                # Log received data
                logging.info(f"Received data: {data}")
                
                # Insert data into the database and send confirmation
                insert_data(conn, data, connection)
                
        except Exception as e:
            # Log errors
            logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
        finally:
            # Close the connection
            connection.close()

# Call the function to start listening

receive_data()

I tried pinging the ip and port using telnet and everything seems good.

If the IP address doesn't belong to your host, there is no way you can listen to it on this host.

Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it.

I think you're mixing server and client connections. If you want to accept connections as a server, you'd bind at 0.0.0.0, for example on the server socket. Connecting with an external server would only need the other's address

Comment from @OneCricketeer solved my problem (copied under CC-BY-SA 4.0):

I think you're mixing server and client connections. If you want to accept connections as a server, you'd bind at 0.0.0.0, for example on the server socket. Connecting with an external server would only need the other's address.

